# Call a cell based on a number

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say I use the function:

```
=INT(MATCH("Test",A1:A100,0))
```

Let's say this gives me 32, is there a way I can call column

```
=AINT(MATCH("Test",A1:A100,0))
```

The reason I would want to do this is to automate a process using a keyword that is not always in the same place.

Something I tried to do is in vba

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'

'
    a = INT(MATCH("Test",A1:A100,0))
    Range("Aa:D40").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select       

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A" & a & ":D40").Select`

Comment: 1 the INT() is not needed. 2. `Range("A" & a & ":D40").Select`

Comment: Also the match is wrong you can't just plug a worksheet formula into vba.  use: `Application.Match("Test",Range("A1:A100"),0)`

Comment: @Scott: Application.WorksheetFunction.Match?

Comment: @SMeaden The WorkSheetFunction will cause the code to stop if a match is not found.  The Application.Match will allow the error to be passed into the variable then it can be tested for the error before proceeding.

Comment: @Scott: Holy Moly!  I never knew that, I thought without WorksheetFunction it would not compile but it does.  And behaviour is as you report.  Well I never knew that.  Cheers.